# Best package for developing a List of Abbreviations

Tags: acronyms

I'm in the process of writing a long document and need a `List of abbreviations`. I've been reading the LaTeX wiki book about this and have had a play with the packages [nomencl](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) and [glossaries](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries). What package is the most straight forward for developing a `List of abbreviations`? Is there a package I've missed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recommend the `glossaries` package. It provides several predefined styles and can be customized very well.

Strengths of `glossaries` are:

- The very good documentation: besides a normal user's manual it offers a beginner's guide and an upgrade guide (from the predecessor `glossary`), and even an author's FAQ, plus well documented source code
- It comes with a Perl script for indexing, running on Linux, Mac as well as on Windows (there's free Perl too)
- It's very actively maintained ([current version on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries?lang=en): 4.35 2017-11-14)
- The author Nicola Talbot provides support in online forums, I frequently see her answering user's questions

Working with `makeindex` is needed for such lists of abbreviations, which might be a hurdle to overcome. The perl script and the extensive documentation of `glossaries` are a great help regarding this step.

Sources for download and documentation:

- [CTAN glossaries page](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries)
- [LaTeX information page](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/index.html) of Nicola L. C. Talbot, with links to her packages, documentation, several LaTeX tutorials and related software

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at glossaries but I was beginning to think it might be too complex. It seems to be able to do lots of stuff I was not going to use. Now it has been recommended I will give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

The `acronym` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\section{Acronym List}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
  \acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication} % [...]
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}
\ac{CDMA} \ac{CDMA} \acl{CDMA}

\end{document}
```

Define the acronyms in the text as

> ```
> \begin{acronym}
>   \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
>   \acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication} % [...]
> \end{acronym}
> ```

The acronyms will appear where defined. To refer to them, use `\ac{CDMA}` which keeps track, presenting first the long form, then the short forms, or `\acs` for the short and `\acl` for the long forms. See https://ctan.org/pkg/acronym?lang=en.

Call f.ex. `pdflatex` twice for the lists.

Pro:

- very simple
- does not require external tools

Con:

- lacks capitalization

Comment: \documentclass... \usepackage{acronym} \begin{document} ...\end{document}...

Comment: Much better -- now everyone can copy the code without to have to build the necessary parts around it...