# Generate a list of Abbreviations which occur in the text?

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

Currently I track my abbreviations manually and put them in a page like below.
I'd like to be able to define the abbreviations inside the text of my paper and then have a list of them automatically printed on a page like this:

**Is that possible and if yes, how?**

[image]

```
\clearpage 
\setstretch{1.5} 
\lhead{\emph{Abbreviations}}

\listofsymbols{ll} % Include a list of Abbreviations (a table of two columns)
{
\textbf{AHRS} & \textbf{A}ttitude and \textbf{H}eading \textbf{R}eference \textbf{S}ystem \\
\textbf{API} & \textbf{A}pplication \textbf{P}rogramming \textbf{I}nterface \\
\textbf{IMU} & \textbf{I}nertial \textbf{M}easurements \textbf{U}nit \\
\textbf{JSON} & \textbf{J}ava\textbf{S}cript \textbf{O}bject \textbf{N}otation \\
\textbf{VGA} & \textbf{V}ideo \textbf{G}raphics \textbf{A}rray  ($640\times480$ px)\\
\textbf{WPF} & \textbf{W}indows \textbf{P}resentation \textbf{F}oundation \\
\textbf{XAML} & E\textbf{x}tended \textbf{A}pplication \textbf{M}arkup \textbf{L}anguage \\
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `glossaries` package, it has this functionality.

Comment: you can see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40915/best-package-for-developing-a-list-of-abbreviations

Comment: Four packages come to mind: [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro), [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) and [`nomencl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl)

Answer (score 4):

This uses the `acronym` way of `glossaries` package.

Each acronym is defined using `\newacronym{label}{Acronym}{Explanation}` in the preamble.

The label is used for reference with `\gls{label}` etc.

To add all defined acronyms, use `\glsaddall`.

Remember to compile twice with `(pdf)latex` and one `makeglossaries` step in between.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ahrs}{AHRS}{\textbf{A}ttitude and \textbf{H}eading \textbf{R}eference \textbf{S}ystem} 
\newacronym{api}{\textbf{API}}{\textbf{A}pplication \textbf{P}rogramming \textbf{I}nterface}%
\newacronym{imu}{IMU}{ \textbf{I}nertial \textbf{M}easurements \textbf{U}nit}
\newacronym{json}{JSON} { \textbf{J}ava\textbf{S}cript \textbf{O}bject \textbf{N}otation}
\newacronym{vga}{VGA}{ \textbf{V}ideo \textbf{G}raphics \textbf{A}rray  ($640\times480$ px)}
\newacronym{wpf}{WPF}{ \textbf{W}indows \textbf{P}resentation \textbf{F}oundation}
\newacronym{xaml}{XAML}{ E\textbf{x}tended \textbf{A}pplication \textbf{M}arkup \textbf{L}anguage}


\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]