# Create a list of abbreviations

Tags: acronyms

They supplied me with a latex template document which is nice for the most part. I just don't succeed in adding a list of abbreviations to it.
This is what I have including where I would like to have such a list:

```
%List of Figures
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\newpage
%List of Tables
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\newpage
%List of Abbreviations

% ?

%References
\renewcommand\refname{References}
\bibliography{literature} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
```

For each of the other elements (figures, tables, references) there is a new page and an entry in the table of contents. Furthermore, the name of each element is printed on top of the page like this:
[image]

How do I add such a page for my abbreviations?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit:**
I tried the package `acronym`. After importing it, I added

```
%List of Tables
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\newpage

%List of Abbreviations
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\section*{Acronym List}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
    \acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication} % [...]
\end{acronym}
\newpage

%Literaturverzeichnis
\renewcommand\refname{References}
\bibliography{literature} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
```

This works mostly fine: I get a new page for my acronyms and even an entry in the Contents. However, it still says "List of Tables" from the section before - how do I change that?
[image]

---

**Edit 2:**
For future visitors: By now I solved it by adding `\markright{List of Abbreviations}` like this:

```
%List of Abbreviations
\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\markright{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
    \acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication} % [...]
\end{acronym}
```

Comment: Hi Julian, welcome to TeX.SE ;-) Do you use a certain package for handeling acronyms?

Comment: Powerful or Simple both described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40915/best-package-for-developing-a-list-of-abbreviations?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! I added some advancements to my post, please have a look!