# Are there 'general' journal abbreviation files/packages for BibTeX/LaTeX? or: Can BibTeX/LaTeX use lists from Endnote (Mendeley, JabRef)?

Tags: bibtex, packages, text, comma-separated-list, journal

Many publishers ask for abbreviations for journal names in the bibliography.

I have checked the links which either need to build the list from the start: [is there a tool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48799/is-there-a-tool-for-generating-journal-names-abbreviations) , or [is there a transparent way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111724/is-there-a-transparent-way-to-automatically-abbreviate-journal-names/423954#423954), or talk about [best package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40915/best-package-for-developing-a-list-of-abbreviations) `acronym` `glossaries` to build the list from ground zero as well, or modify the `.bst` with a new `journal.abbrev` function and other changes [Abbreviation using .bst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550650/abbreviation-of-journal-names-using-bst?noredirect=1&lq=1), or a [compholio package](http://www.compholio.com/latex/jabbrv/) which is not simple or 'general' for using it.

But none of those meets the need.

Endnote has a lot of `.txt` files as terms list, with names separated by `Tabs`, e.g. (the block quotes below cannot show the `Tabs` before the `J.`)

> Journal of Business and Psychology    J. Bus. Psychol.    J Bus Psychol

> Journal of Business Strategy  J. Bus. Strategy    J Bus Strategy

> Journal of Cancer Education   J. Cancer Educ. J Cancer Educ

The term-lists contain more than 10k names, which are sufficient for general use.

My question is, are there similar files/packages for BibTeX/LaTeX to `import/include`, which are general enough for normal `.bst` to process and output the abbreviated journal names to the bibliography in the PDF?

If no such files/packages, is there a way for BibTeX/LaTeX to use term-lists from Endnote? or other reference management software, such as JabRef or Mendeley? (though I have not tried JabRef, and cannot find how to EXPORT the list from Mendeley, which cannot be copied/pasted into .txt or excel. Any ideas how to EXPORT Mendeley's list?)

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not believe that BibTeX or even BibLaTeX can itself abbreviate journal names. However, JabRef has the option to abbreviate journal names in the "Quality" menu. Under "Options" you can "Manage journal abbreviations", which allows to you read your own abbreviation lists. In Jabref, these are .csv files, so you can easily modify your EndNote lists to work in JabRef as well.

Comment: Thanks, yes most reference management software provides journal abbreviation database/lists, e.g. Mendeley, Zotero, Endnote, and JabRef is similar I believe though I do not use it. But I want to find similar solution in BibTeX/LaTeX.

Comment: Well, if you insist on doing it on the fly, that maybe [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33441/how-to-abbreviate-journal-name-in-citation) is helpful for you.

Comment: you can use @string to manage different variants.

Comment: Thank you Manuel and Ulrike, I have checked the mentioned thread, or using @string etc., which is also talking about building the list manually one item by one item, instead of a 'general' solution which can be reused by others.